# Command Prompt Navigation: Navigating To An Unknownly Named Folder

Tags: cmd, edit, cd

So, is there any way to navigate your command prompt to/through a location which's name you don't know exactly?

For example the situation is i want to rename the sei.dat file and its located at:

`C:/programdata/CsD2/Tools/("THE UNKNOWN VERSION NAMED FOLDER")/data/per/sei.dat`

So as you can see i know where the software is installed however the folder after "Tools" folder is named after the version of the tools (example V0.1.2.6) and it changes often.
Is there any command or way to navigate the Command Prompt to the files location? Or if not is there any way to modify the file without navigating the Command Prompt to the location?

I just want to rename the file but i don't know the name of the folder marked as "THE UNKNOWN VERSION NAMED FOLDER"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "C:\programdata\CsD2\Tools\sei.dat" ') do set "folder=%%~dpa"
if not defined folder echo sei.dat was not found & pause & goto :EOF
cd /d "%folder%"
cmd /k
```

Comment: Well not doing anything for me as i can see :/ But what is it suppose to do? I mean i don't really understand how does the Command Prompt works yet.

Comment: sei.dat was not found & nothing changed

Comment: C:\ProgramData\CsD2\Tools\V1.10.12.3\data\per and here you can find the sei.dat but as i said the V1.10.12.3 chages often and i want to be able to navigate my Command Prompt there even tho i don't know the version

Comment: I just want to navigate my Command Prompt to this location C:\ProgramData\CsD2\Tools\V1.10.12.3\data\per without knowing the folder named V1.10.12.3's name

Comment: Nothing just prints C:\ProgramData\CsD2\Tools\V1.10.12.3\data\per\sei.dat

Comment: I created a file at "C:\ProgramData\CsD2\Tools\V1.10.12.3\data\per\sei.dat" and the batch file works for me.

Comment: OMG i was so stupid i forgot that for me CMD is kinda a bit broken
I managed to get it work with your command sorry for takeing your time