# Command Prompt: Move a file to an Unknownly named folder

Tags: cmd, move

So, is there a possible way to move Test.txt to `C:\ProgramData\CsD2\Tools\("Unknown Folder Name")\data\per` Using command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using foxidrives solution for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890671/2152082) for detecting the correct directory, then just

```
move test.txt "%folder%\"
```

Comment: You mean after i did what he showed me

Just: move "C:/test.txt" "%folder%/test.txt" ?

Comment: exactly. If you don't want to change the name of the file, you can omit it at the destination (as I wrote in my answer). But it works also with the filename given, as you wrote it in your comment.

Comment: Can you tell me please how can i refer in the move command to the folder where i am at the moment i mean i'm at the folder "%folder%" and i want to move the file to the folder without writing the "%folder%"? Like a short cut refers to the folder i'm in ATM if you know what i mean.

Comment: `move c:\test.txt` (without giving an explicite destination, it moves to the current working directory and keeps the filename).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. Not quite sure what the situation is that has left only the middle part of your path unknown, and the need to use the comnand line, but I have encountered similar cases on Linux and expect the algoirthm can be adapted to Windows commands. It's possible to do this by hand rather than writing a shell script, but it's up to you and your skills.

Permissions matter. Make sure you elevate yours enough to read and write in Tools before continuing.

First, change directory to C:\ProgramData\CsD2\Tools\

Presumably there are many items here. Some may be "hidden," so list the contents of this directory and be sure to include an option to show hidden files and folders. If you can, restrict the search to directories only.

It's tempting to display contents recursively in the above step. It's up to you, but I find it makes the output cluttered without a script to do the rest of the work.

Now it's time to search for the subfolder set that theoretically only exists in your target folder. Suppose Tools contains the directories fldr1, fldr2, and fldr3. Use your command to list a directory's contents with the path "fldr1\data\per", then use "fldr2\data\per", and so on until it doesn't return an error. Per may be empty, but that should look different from the path not found error.

Now you've found the name of your mystery folder. Write it down for future reference.

At thus point, you know the path to Test.txt, and the full path to the destination directory. Do a move command to relocate Test.txt, and you're done. I like to relist the contents of the target directory after to be comfortable that it arrived.